# Change date month from Hijri to Gregorian

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, date-conversion

I have table in which I have two columns with name "Month" and "Year"

Here are there values "4" and "1438" respectively both column values are from Hijri calendar.

Now I want to change all values of month in table from Hijri to Gregorian.

I just tried to do so for one value in this way,

```
select convert(datetime, value, 131)
from (
    values ('01-04-1424  9:54:59:767AM')
    ) samples(value)
```

It has successfully changed it to "2003-06-01 09:54:59.767"

But how can I change all values of month column from table my table name is "Employ"

Hope for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace column name instead of value

```
 SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, concat('01-', month_column,'-', year_column), 131) FROM Employ
```

Comment: Does it directly convert month column values or i will just see what will be the changes ?

Comment: This is the just select query. you can run and check the output which you expect

Comment: yes it is working good but i need only month values after conversion like i had month column only. After conversion it shows me month only

Comment: Share the output which you want. I didnt get what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for your query i used format to get month value only.